# Need to create function in Python that finds all complex and real roots of z^n=x(so the nth-roots of x)

Tags: python

beginner programmer here. I have been assigned to create a function 'Roots' that takes two parameters x and n(n has to be an integer) and then calculates all complex and real roots of the equation z^n=x. However, the only module/package I can use is math. Also, I have been told that the certain aspects of the following function 'Power_complex' play a big role into creating 'Roots':

```
def Power_complex(re, im, n):     #calculates the n-th power of a complex number(lets call this a), where 're' is the real part and 'im' the imaginary part
import math
r=math.sqrt((re)**2+(im)**2)      #calculates modulus
h=math.atan2(re,im)               #calculates argument(angle)
ren=(r**n)*math.cos(h*n)          #calculates the real part of a^n
imn=(r**n)*math.sin(h*n)          #calculates the imaginary part of a^n
return ren, imn
print '(',re, '+', im, 'i',')','^',n,'=',ren,'+',imn,'i' #displays the result
```

Also, I need to somehow implement a for loop into 'Roots'.
I have been pondering over this for hours, but alas I really can't figure it out and am hoping one of you can help me out here.

BTW my python version is 2.7.10

Comment: Do you know the mathematical expressions for the roots of that equation?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.  
StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service.

Comment: If I understand your question so far, you have yet to post any code of your own.  How is it that you've been pondering for hours over a problem whose solution is readily found with a web search?
I entered "complex nth roots", went to the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nth_root) for the topic, and found the solution near the bottom, under headings "Roots of unity" and "nth roots".  Does this get you moving?

Comment: @user2357112 I'm afraid I really don't know what you mean with mathematical expressions, but I think it should be sufficient to know that the roots must be complex or real.

Comment: @Prune Well, the problem really wasn't that I couldn't find how to find the roots, it was more of implementing it all into a file in the way I described above. I'm really new to programming so sorry if I sound a bit, well stupid :/

Answer (score 1):

The expression for the solutions is ( [explained here](http://www-thphys.physics.ox.ac.uk/people/FrancescoHautmann/Cp4/sl_clx_11_4_cls.pdf) ):

[image: z = r^(1/n) e^(i * (theta + 2*pi*k) / n ) for k = {0, 1, ... , n-1}]

when

[image: z^n = r e^( i*theta )]

In the case that z^n is real, equal to the x in your question, then r = |x| and the angle is 0 or pi for positive and negative values, respectively.

So you make the modulus and argument as you have done, then make every solution corresponding to a value of k

```
z = [r**(1./n) * exp(1j * (theta + 2*pi*k) / n ) for k in range(n)]
```

This line uses a Python technique called list comprehension. An eqvivalent  way of doing it (that you may be more familiar to) could be:

```
z = []
for k in range(n):
    nthroot = r**(1./n) * exp( 1j * (theta + 2*pi*k) / n )
    z.append(nthroot)
```

Printing them out could be done in the same fashion, using a for-loop:

```
for i in range(len(z)):
    print "Root #%d = %g + i*%g" % (i, z[i].real, z[i].imag)
```

Note that the `exp`-function used must be from the module `cmath` (`math` can't handle complex numbers). If you are not allowed to use `cmath`, then I suggest you rewrite the expression for the solutions to the form without modulus and argument.

Comment: Ok, so after reading those sheets, I somehow understand that the amount of roots depends on the value of 'n'. I also forgot to mention x should be a real number, but that would still be a complex number if I am correct(so x=re + 0i). 

So should I first calculate the modulus(=r) and angle/theta(=h), and then just create a for loop for k in range(n) and in that loop calculate consecutively the roots with the line of code you suggested?

And btw if I calculated those roots, what exactly would be an easy way to print them all at once, and maybe if possible give them all a distinct name(z1, z2..)

Comment: @ J.Sparrow The above code gives you a list of solutions. I'll add a more explicit version that may be more familiar. I don't think you want to give all the roots their own variable (it could be many), they are probably best stored in a list.

Comment: @J.Sparrow If the answer helped you out, please consider accepting the answer and/or up voting.